# Spring @Autowired can not wire Jpa repository

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I clearly missing something here.
I'm making a simple `spring boot` app with `spring data jpa` inluded and face follwing error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [locassa.domain.repository.PersonRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1373) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1119) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    ... 32 common frames omitted
```

My code:

Application:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"app.controller", "app.domain"})
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>pl.mosek</groupId>
    <artifactId>pl.mosek</artifactId>
    <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.16.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Controller:

```
@RestController
public class TestController {

    @Autowired
    PersonService personService;

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index() {
        return "Test spring boot";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/person/{id}")
    public Person personById(@PathVariable Long id) {
        return personService.findPerson(id);
    }
}
```

PersonService:

```
public interface PersonService {

    Person findPerson(Long id);
}
```

PersonServiceImpl:

```
@Service
public class PersonServiceImpl implements PersonService {

    @Autowired
    PersonRepository personRepository;

    public Person findPerson(Long id) {
       return personRepository.findOne(id);
    }
}
```

PersonRepository (this one cannot be autowired):

```
public interface PersonRepository extends CrudRepository<Person, Long> {
}
```

Searched on the web already. I didnt found a thing. Any ideas?

Comment: @SpringBootApplication
@EntityScan("<@Entitiy classes package>")public class Application {}, is enough, remove extra annotations.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I also had the same problem.I solved it with following solution. If your Entity classes and Repositories in a different package you need to use following annotations.

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"EntityPackage"} )
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"RepositoryPackage"})
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);

    }
}
```

Comment: Both of them are under `app.domain`. Entities are under `app.domain.model` and repositories under `app.domain.repository`

Comment: I tried `@EnableJpaRepositories` but without combinationwith `@EntityScan`. Both of those annotations solve the isssue.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: So you don't need the autowire?

Comment: I am not using spring boot, so @EntityScan is not located? is it boot is mandatory to use this ?

Comment: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan and org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories class solved my problem, I need to use both of them

Comment: This fix the issue.I add @ComponentScan(basePackages = {"basepackage"}) too.Thank you very much.