# Spring Boot @Autowired Jpa repository returns Null

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, activemq-classic, spring-data-jpa

I am currently working on a Spring boot based application that also integrates with ActiveMQ functionality , to handle DB updates between two different applications. I am currenly trying to integrate default functionality provided by spring data jpa (with hibernate) to handle the DB related operation.
when attempting to save the recieved date into the database using JpaRepository  it is indicated as Null.

**Refered Links for similar scenarios**

[Spring @Autowired can not wire Jpa repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34169321/spring-autowired-can-not-wire-jpa-repository#)

**Other Resources**

https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/

Exception

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at samples.reportdata.reports.sampleSalesReport_Observer.createSampleSalesRecord(sampleSalesReport_Observer.java:107)
    at samples.reportdata.reports.sampleSalesReport_Observer.update(sampleSalesReport_Observer.java:23)
    at samples.reportdata.reports.BaseReport.call(BaseReport.java:36)
    at samples.reportdata.observer.observers.BaseObserver.update(BaseObserver.java:39)
    at samples.reportdata.observer.subject.BaseSubject.notifyAllObservers(BaseSubject.java:36)
    at samples.reportdata.observer.subject.BaseSubject.setMessage(BaseSubject.java:70)
    at samples.reportdata.utilities.CommonConsumer.process(CommonConsumer.java:127)
    at samples.reportdata.Controller.reportController(Controller.java:30)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:220)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:134)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:116)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at samples.reportdata.filters.CrossOriginRequestSharingFilter.doFilter(CrossOriginRequestSharingFilter.java:57)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:89)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:117)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:61)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1099)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:670)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)strong text
```

**My code segements:**

*Application*

```
  package samples.reportdata;

    import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
    import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

    import samples.reportdata.utilities.CommonLoader;

      @SpringBootApplication
      /*@Configuration
        @ComponentScan
        @EnableAutoConfiguration
        @EntityScan(basePackages = {"samples.reportdata.pojo"})
        @EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"samples.reportdata.repository"})
        @EnableTransactionManagement*/
        public class RezgReportDataServiceApplication {

            public static void main(String[] args) {
                new CommonLoader();
                SpringApplication.run(RezgReportDataServiceApplication.class, args);
            }

        }
```

**Controller**

Note:that acts as the entry point for data recieved from Active MQ*

```
  package samples.reportdata;

    import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
    import java.net.URLDecoder;

    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

    import samples.reportdata.utilities.CommonConsumer;

    @RestController
    public class Controller {

        @RequestMapping(value = "/receive", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public String reportController(@RequestBody String postPayload, @RequestParam(value = "queue") String queue) {
            String msg = "";
            try {
                System.out.println("queue==>" + queue);
                System.out.println(URLDecoder.decode(postPayload, "UTF-8"));
                msg = CommonConsumer.getInstance().process(URLDecoder.decode(postPayload, "UTF-8"), queue.split("queue://")[1]);
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return msg;
        }
    }
```

Entity Class
The persistent class for the sample_sales_report database table.

```
package samples.reportdata.pojo;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Date;

@Entity
@Table(schema="rezbase_v3_reports", name="sample_sales_report")
@NamedQuery(name="sampleSalesReport.findAll", query="SELECT t FROM sampleSalesReport t")
public class sampleSalesReport implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(unique=true, nullable=false)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name="booking_channel", length=5)
    private String bookingChannel;

    @Column(name="cancel_charges")
    private double cancelCharges;

    @Column(name="cancel_charges_base")
    private double cancelChargesBase;

    @Column(name="cash_base_fare")
    private double cashBaseFare;

    @Column(name="cash_base_fare_base")
    private double cashBaseFareBase;

    @Column(name="cash_currency", length=10)
    private String cashCurrency;

    @Column(name="cash_land_fare")
    private double cashLandFare;

    @Column(name="cash_land_fare_base")
    private double cashLandFareBase;

    @Column(name="cash_other_tax")
    private double cashOtherTax;

    @Column(name="cash_other_tax_base")
    private double cashOtherTaxBase;

    @Column(name="cash_tot_tax")
    private double cashTotTax;

    @Column(name="cash_tot_tax_base")
    private double cashTotTaxBase;

    @Column(name="cash_yqyrtax")
    private double cashYqyrtax;

    @Column(name="cash_yqyrtax_base")
    private double cashYqyrtaxBase;

    @Column(name="city_id")
    private Integer cityId;

    @Column(name="city_name", length=50)
    private String cityName;

    @Column(length=5)
    private String combination;

    @Column(name="country_id")
    private Integer countryId;

    @Column(name="country_name", length=50)
    private String countryName;

    @Column(name="credit_base_fare")
    private double creditBaseFare;

    @Column(name="credit_base_fare_base")
    private double creditBaseFareBase;

    @Column(name="credit_currency", length=5)
    private String creditCurrency;

    @Column(name="credit_land_fare")
    private double creditLandFare;

    @Column(name="credit_land_fare_base")
    private double creditLandFareBase;

    @Column(name="credit_other_tax")
    private double creditOtherTax;

    @Column(name="credit_other_tax_base")
    private double creditOtherTaxBase;

    @Column(name="credit_tot_tax")
    private double creditTotTax;

    @Column(name="credit_tot_tax_base")
    private double creditTotTaxBase;

    @Column(name="credit_yqyrtax")
    private double creditYqyrtax;

    @Column(name="credit_yqyrtax_base")
    private double creditYqyrtaxBase;

    @Column(name="eticket_number", length=15)
    private String eticketNumber;

    @Column(name="flight_included", length=3)
    private String flightIncluded;

    @Column(length=3)
    private String packagetype;

    @Column(name="passenger_type", length=5)
    private String passengerType;

    @Column(name="payment_category", length=10)
    private String paymentCategory;

    @Column(name="pkg_name", length=40)
    private String pkgName;

    @Column(name="pkg_reservation_number", length=15)
    private String pkgReservationNumber;

    @Column(name="portal_id", length=50)
    private String portalId;

    @Column(name="pos_agent_commision")
    private double posAgentCommision;

    @Column(name="pos_agent_commision_percentage")
    private double posAgentCommisionPercentage;

    @Column(name="pos_gsa_commision")
    private double posGsaCommision;

    @Column(name="pos_gsa_commision_percentage")
    private double posGsaCommisionPercentage;

    @Column(name="pos_total_commision")
    private double posTotalCommision;

    @Column(name="poslocation_currency", length=4)
    private String poslocationCurrency;

    @Column(name="poslocation_currency_id")
    private Integer poslocationCurrencyId;

    @Column(name="poslocation_id")
    private Integer poslocationId;

    @Column(name="poslocation_name", length=50)
    private String poslocationName;

    @Column(name="product_type", length=1)
    private String productType;

    @Column(length=50)
    private String region;

    @Column(name="region_id")
    private Integer regionId;

    private Integer resconfirmid;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name="reservation_date")
    private Date reservationDate;

    @Column(name="reservation_no", length=15)
    private String reservationNo;

    private Integer respkgconfirmid;

    @Column(length=2)
    private String resstatus;

    @Column(name="supconf_number", length=20)
    private String supconfNumber;

    @Column(name="total_cancelation_charge")
    private double totalCancelationCharge;

    @Column(name="total_cancelation_charge_base")
    private double totalCancelationChargeBase;

    private double yqyrtax;

    @Column(name="yqyrtax_base")
    private double yqyrtaxBase;

    public sampleSalesReport() {
    }

    /*Note:Getters and setters for above mentioned fields have been omitted for clarity*/

    }
```

/*sampleSalesReportRepository (Note :this one cannot be autowired and return Null)*/

```
package samples.reportdata.repository;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import samples.reportdata.pojo.sampleSalesReport;

@Repository
public interface sampleSalesReportRepository extends JpaRepository<sampleSalesReport, Integer>   {

    List<sampleSalesReport> findAll();

    sampleSalesReport findOne(Integer id);
}
```

**Service**

```
package samples.reportdata.reports;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.ws.soap.Addressing;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import samples.reportdata.pojo.sampleSalesReport;
import samples.reportdata.repository.sampleSalesReportRepository;

@ComponentScan
public class sampleSalesReport_Observer extends BaseReport {

    @Override
    public void update() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("sampleSalesReport_Observer " + this.getSubject().getData());
        this.setMessage("message");
        try {
            createSampleSalesRecord();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

  /*Note:This is the Object that does not get auto wired*/
    @Autowired
    private sampleSalesReportRepository sampleSalesReportRepository;

    /*Save Sample Record to DB*/
    public List<sampleSalesReport> createSampleSalesRecord() {

       //Note:sample data set to check JPA operation
        sampleSalesReport sampleSalesReport= new sampleSalesReport();
        Date dNow = new Date( );

        sampleSalesReport.setId(6);
        sampleSalesReport.setProductType("F");
        sampleSalesReport.setResconfirmid(123);
        sampleSalesReport.setRegion("Asia");
        sampleSalesReport.setRegionId(21);
        sampleSalesReport.setCountryName("Sri Lanka");
        sampleSalesReport.setCountryId(123);
        sampleSalesReport.setCityId(22);
        sampleSalesReport.setCityName("Colombo");
        sampleSalesReport.setPoslocationName("Pos_colombo");
        sampleSalesReport.setPoslocationId(100);
        sampleSalesReport.setBookingChannel("CC");
        sampleSalesReport.setPoslocationCurrency("LKR");
        sampleSalesReport.setPoslocationCurrencyId(180);
        sampleSalesReport.setReservationDate(dNow);
        sampleSalesReport.setFlightIncluded("F");
        sampleSalesReport.setPkgReservationNumber("P1234567");
        sampleSalesReport.setPackagetype("D");
        sampleSalesReport.setCombination("FHA");
        sampleSalesReport.setReservationNo("F0001W090308");
        sampleSalesReport.setEticketNumber("1571234567890");
        sampleSalesReport.setPkgName("FlightOne");
        sampleSalesReport.setPaymentCategory("Credit");
        sampleSalesReport.setSupconfNumber("PAY-12345678");
        sampleSalesReport.setPassengerType("ADT");
        sampleSalesReport.setPosAgentCommisionPercentage(10.00);
        sampleSalesReport.setPosAgentCommision(20.33);
        sampleSalesReport.setPosAgentCommisionPercentage(12.00);
        sampleSalesReport.setPosAgentCommision(30.66);
        sampleSalesReport.setPosTotalCommision(50.99);
        sampleSalesReport.setResstatus("N");
        sampleSalesReport.setCashCurrency("LKR");
        sampleSalesReport.setCashLandFare(100.00);
        sampleSalesReport.setCashBaseFare(100.00);
        sampleSalesReport.setCashTotTax(220.00);
        sampleSalesReport.setCashYqyrtax(10.00);
        sampleSalesReport.setCashOtherTax(10.00);
        sampleSalesReport.setCashLandFareBase(100.00);
        sampleSalesReport.setCashBaseFareBase(100.00);
        sampleSalesReport.setCashTotTaxBase(220.00);
        sampleSalesReport.setCashYqyrtaxBase(10.00);
        sampleSalesReport.setCashOtherTaxBase(10.00);
        sampleSalesReport.setCreditCurrency("OMR");
        sampleSalesReport.setCreditLandFare(200.00);
        sampleSalesReport.setCreditBaseFare(200.00);
        sampleSalesReport.setCreditTotTax(440.00);
        sampleSalesReport.setCreditYqyrtax(20.00);
        sampleSalesReport.setCreditOtherTax(20.00);
        sampleSalesReport.setCreditLandFareBase(200.00);
        sampleSalesReport.setCreditBaseFareBase(200.00);
        sampleSalesReport.setCreditTotTaxBase(440.00);
        sampleSalesReport.setCreditYqyrtaxBase(20.00);
        sampleSalesReport.setCreditOtherTaxBase(20.00);
        sampleSalesReport.setYqyrtax(40.00);
        sampleSalesReport.setYqyrtaxBase(80.00);
        sampleSalesReport.setCancelCharges(1.00);
        sampleSalesReport.setCancelChargesBase(2.00);
        sampleSalesReport.setTotalCancelationCharge(1.00);
        sampleSalesReport.setTotalCancelationChargeBase(2.00);

      /*Note: This is the line the nullpoint is thrown for sampleSalesReportRepository*/
        sampleSalesReportRepository.save(sampleSalesReport);

        return sampleSalesReportRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the ugly `COmmonConsumer.getInstance()` do... Is there a new `sampleSalesReport_Observer` in there? Also it should possibly be a `@Component` (or `@Service`) instead of `@ComponentScan`.

Comment: this is because you are creating a new object. remove this - sampleSalesReport sampleSalesReport= new sampleSalesReport();

Answer (score 2):

You should use `@Component` instead of `@ComponentScan` for the  class `sampleSalesReport_Observer`.

Answer (score 0):

You have applied incorrect annotation `@ComponentScan` on `sampleSalesReport_Observer`.

Remove it and apply `@Component` instead.

`@Component` will make it eligible to be treated as a `component` when your spring boot application scans for the registered `component`s and here in your case it is `sampleSalesReport_Observer` and once it is found all the required dependencies / beans / other registered components will be `autowired` as per your requirement. In your case it is failing on `sampleSalesReportRepository` because the `sampleSalesReport_Observer` was never detected as a `component`.